# formula field to retun a specific value

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have below formula field now I need to update this formula as if one of the fields is blank then it should return 1 and if 2 fields are blank then it should return 2 and so on for 3, 4 and 5.

```
IF(  AND( ISBLANK(Email),
          ISBLANK(Phone),
          ISBLANK(Company),
          ISBLANK(Title), 
          ISPICKVAL(Industry, '') )  , 0, 5)
```

Can someone please help me to achive the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can check condition and do addition of returned value of condition.

Your formula should look like:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Email), 1, 0)
+ IF(ISBLANK(Phone), 1, 0)
+ IF(ISBLANK(Company), 1, 0)
+ IF(ISBLANK(Title), 1, 0)
+ IF(ISPICKVAL(Industry, ''), 1, 0)
```